# Change store details Adaptive Payments API

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm integrating paypal Adaptive Payments and when "the sender" is sending funds to "the receiver" for some reason it shows "The API Caller" store name (in the picture below). How can I make it so it will show receivers store name or email address instead? I went over entire manual and cannot figure it out, please help, thanks.

here is picture http://s28.postimg.org/4xeqxfylp/pp_issue.png